# Order of evaluation for the vector cross product

Tags: cross-product

Since the vector cross product is non-associative, is the is the expression A x B x C (without parentheses) meaningless?  Or is there a convention for the order of evaluation (left to right or right to left) if there are no parentheses present?

Answer (score 1):

Since cross product is not associative $A\times B\times C$ is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

If the context doesn't tell you anything and you don't have any parentheses you should evaluate from left to right as long as I learned.